# Extracting a specific word from another given string

Tags: c#, string

I would like to know if there is a way in C# to extract a specific word from a given String. For Example, my code has the following:

1. `string emblem = "tiger"`
2. `string userEntered = "a12tdddgh22i333gs4444e99rt"`

I need a way to check if the `userEntered` string has the characters **t**, **i**, **g**, **e**, **r** and then compare it with the `emblem` string value. In most cases, the `userEntered` string will be scrambled, so is there a logical way to compare the extracted characters with the value in `emblem`?

Any inputs would be really appreciated.

Comment: Most likely, there is a way to do this.

Comment: Do the letters have to be in order or just in the entered string?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ekartik! SO isn't (usually?) a code _writing_ service, however, we are here to help if you get stuck. What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: Are you looking for something like the [Levenshtein_distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)?

Comment: Take a look @ this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem or this: https://github.com/mdi1984/RKR-GST/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I don't see any code, so I can't help

Answer (score 3):

You can try *Linq* with *side effect* (we change `startIndex` while querying):

```
string emblem = "tiger";
string userEntered = "a12tdddgh22i333gs4444e99rt";

int startIndex = -1;

bool found = emblem
  .All(c => (startIndex = userEntered.IndexOf(c, startIndex + 1)) >= 0);
```

We should ensure

1. *All* characters within `emblem` are in the `userEntered`
2. If character `c1` in `emblem` appears *before* `c2` then `userEntered.IndexOf(c1) < userEntered.IndexOf(c2)`

In the sample above we have `found == true` since

> a12**t**dddgh22**i**333**g**s4444**e**99**r**t

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool containsString(string word, string input) 
{
    string pattern = Regex.Replace(word, ".", ".*$0");
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

    return Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options).Count > 0;
}

...

string input = @"a12tdddgh22i333gs4444e99rt";
string word = "tiger";

bool found = containsString(word, input);
Console.WriteLine($"found: {found}");
```

Comment: Isn't Regex slow on smaller strings?